# Combination of the with and cycle django templatetags

Tags: django, django-templates

i've 2 for loop in a django template file, and i'd like to *generate* the value of the cycle templatetags in the first loop, but using it in the second. Somehow like this:

```
{% for item in firstloop %}
    {% with requiredvalue=!cycle 'red' 'blue' 'green'! %}
        {% for inneritem in innerforloop %}
            {{ requiredvalue }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

. This is not a working code of course, but if the firstloop has 3 elements, and innerforloop has 2 elements, i'd like to get this result: red, red, blue, blue, green, green .

Is it somehow doable on the template side?

Thanks.

Comment: please share what value firstloop and innerforloop contains

Answer (score 0):

Now, this seems weird, but you can't do a count in Django's loop. What you should do is to pass (literally) everything as a part of your context and then render it.

Let's say your context look like this:

```py
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # ...
    context['colors'] = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
    context['loop_times'] = range(1, 2)
```

Then your template will look something like this:

```
{% for color in colors %}  // cycles red, green, blue
    {% for i in loop_times %}  // repeats two times
        <p>{{ color }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Of course, I don't know what your `color` is in terms of type, so you might need to make some slight adjustments yourself, but this is briefly how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the full context of your code it is hard to answer. But if your second for loop is dependent on the first you can do the following:

```
{% for item in firstloop %}
  {% for subitem in item % }
    // Do Stuff
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If the second loop is unrelated to the second, you can use {% ifchanged %}

```
{% for item in firstloop %}
  {% ifchanged item %}
    {% for second_item in secondloop % }
      // Do Stuff
    {% endfor %}
  {% endifchanged %}
{% endfor %}
```